# not able to escape regex using karate framework on IntelliJ

Tags: java, regex, escaping, gherkin, karate

I'm testing a web service using karate framework using IntelliJ.

By framework definition, I should be able to use regex to assert XML responses and I have been able to use it to some extent.

But the problem arises when I want to assert using regex which contains back-slash, for example: `"\X{20,}"`
So I tried: (using 3 back-slashes \\\)

**Then match response ...... rawData == '#regex \\\X{20,}'**

[image: screenshot of Gherkin code]

and this gives me an error:

> **com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
>   \X{20,}**

Comment: A literal backslash in a Java regex context is actually _four_ backslashes in a row.  Basically, two backslashes gives you a literal backlash, which itself in turn needs to be escaped again.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `\\\X{20,}` cannot be valid. Double backslash is required in your feature file.

So `\\` represents a single regex backslash (meant to escape what follows it). If you want to match a single literal `\` in your regex, you need `\\\\` in the feature file.

So your pattern should probably be `\\\\X{20,}` if the content should contain a backslash.

This is documented [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching).

> Note that regex escaping has to be done with a double back-slash - for e.g: '#regex a\.dot' will match 'a.dot'